# Load and modify xml file in Android

Tags: android, xml

I have an xml file which will be in either assets or res folder which i need to modify by adding some values and then i need to convert the xml into a string to be sent as part of a soap request. What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't modify resource files.

If you don't need modify resources, you can put the XML file in assets folder. Then you can access it by `AssetManager` (returns by `getResources().getAssets()`). With `AssetManager` you can get `InputStream` from XML file or use `XMLResourceParser`. And do with it whatever you want.

Comment: I put it in the assets folder and used an input stream reader to read the file all into one string. I then replaced placeholders in the file with the values from the user input. Seems to work fine